# Realm add doesn’t insert all objects

Tags: ios, swift, realm

In my app, I am getting 1000 objects per request and inserting them in realm database.  Total number of requests is 7, but not all data are inserted. At the end, there should have been 6236 objects, whereas I am getting only 6070 objects.
I tried with `realm.create` method as well by iterating all of them, but still same result. I am not getting any error messages for failure queries. Is there any way to get the failure messages?

My insertion code is:

```
func saveAyahs(ayahs: [Ayah]) {
    print("From API")
    print(ayahs.count)
    do{
        let realm = try Realm()
        try realm.write {
            realm.add(ayahs, update: true)
 //                for items in ayahs {
 //                    try realm.create(Ayah.self, value: items, update: true)
 //                }
            print(realm.objects(Ayah.self).count)
        }
    }catch {
        print("Unexpected error: \(error).")
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't print the number of objects inside the write transaction, but should do it after the write transaction.

Comment: okay i tried that. And datas are not actually getting inserted. I checked with realm studio as well

Comment: did you find a way to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that some of the Ayahs have the same key/identifer?

Comment: I have the same problem and, one of my objects has the primary key same as the parent object.

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
        realm.add(ayahs, update: true)
```

Your Object **Ayah**

It seems, you have primary key - id, or another, where its updating same object with other key.

Try removing primary key, check it.

I will edit my answer, if you share, Ayah class.

You should remove

```
    print(realm.objects(Ayah.self).count)
```

from method inside,& show when method ends operation.